# Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion

Tags: windows-7, windows-services, timeout

I would like to increase the default 30s service timeout period on my Windows 7 64bit system. My SQL Server Express service fails to start a lot of times on boot. I found these instructions: http://www.itgeekdiary.com/increase-the-service-timeout-period/

but there is no `ServicesPipeTimeout` key under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control` in my Registry

How can I set this up to a higher value than 30s?

Comment: I have the same problem and ServicesPipeTimeout=60000 helps me

Comment: Not sure if this helps but I know for a fact that I had errors in my windows registry (Windows 10) when I got 'Error 1053' and 'The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion'. Fixing the registry solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I'm supposed to create ServicesPipeTimeout DWORD entry and set the value... from all the articles on the web it looked like the entry should have been already present and set to 30000 (ms)... So I created it and I will see if it had any effect.